# How to delete Home and Work address from My Places?

Tags: stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I was messing around on my phone and found "My Places" in the settings (Settings> Location> My Places). I set up a home and a work location thinking that I would be able to delete it afterwards.

However I have not found how to do this. I removed these location from Google Maps and Google Now, but I can't remove them from My Places. I also cannot change the method of them to WiFi or Bluetooth.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900F)

Android: 4.4.2

Thank you.

Comment: You can delete them with Android 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Open Google Maps on your phone, press the white rectangular button with three horizontal lines. It's located in the bottom left corner in Google Maps. Choose `Settings`and `Edit home or work`.

Hope this helps you out.

--UPDATE--

You could also try to log in to `google.com` from a computer and choose `google maps` from the app-list (a small icon at the top-right corner with 3x3 dots). Next, click the settings-cog-wheel at the bottom-right corner in google maps and choose `my places`. Finally click on the drop-down next to `my home` and `my work` and click delete.

Comment: There are no addresses saved in Google Maps or Google Now. The only place they are saved is in Settings> Location> My Places

Comment: OK, try to log in to google.com from a computer and choose google maps from the app-list (a small icon at the top-right corner with 3x3 dots).

Next, click the settings-cog-wheel at the bottom-right corner in google maps and choose `my places`.
Finally click on the drop-down next to `my home` and `my work`and click delete.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Google maps app
2. Open Menu (three lines on tope left) **>** Your Places
3. Now you can see "Home" and "Work" listed on the screen
4. Touch (x) button on the right to "Home"/"Work". whichever you want to delete.

EDIT: for newer version of Google Maps

4. Touch "three dots" and select "Remove home" / "Remove work"

Answer (score 1):

In the [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) you can do the following:

Swipe open the menu on the right → Customize → Tap on work or home and edit them (blank to delete).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Notification setting]

Comment: This option doesn't work for me as it just goes back to the originally saved work address. Hope it helps others though!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible on the phone to amend the locations but it's definitely not possible to delete...to amend...Settings, Location and then Mode. This allows you to change which service to find you, be it Wifi, GPS or mobile networks. Then go back and click on My Places and select either Home or Work and you'll see a smallish map appear. Directly above click on the word Maps and this opens a much larger one, by clicking on the location pointer to the right of Search the phone should then try to find you.